# Busca no google maps api retorna valores diferentes com curl ou guzzle

Tags: php, google-maps, libcurl, google-maps-api-3, guzzle

Eu faço a pesquisa na api do google maps com o curl ou o guzzle usando php e me retorna um valor diferente que usando o postman ou o navegador

ex:

```
$client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET', $url,[
        'query' => [
            'type' => 'gas_station',
            'query' => 'Uberlandia,MG',
            'key' => 'MYKEY',
        ],
    ]);
```

isso me retorna

```
{"html_attributions":[],"results":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS"}
```

mas no navegador ou no postman me retorna valores pela url

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?type=gas_station&query=Uberlandia%2CMG&key=MYKEY
```

Não é apenas essa pesquisa, várias retornam esse erro

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json";
$client = new Client();
$res    = $client->request('GET', $url, [
  'headers' => [
    'User-Agent'    => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 
  Safari/537.36',
      'Accept'        => 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
],
'query' => [
    'type' => 'gas_station',
    'keyword' => 'posto,combustiveis',
    'query' => 'lago sul - Shi Sul Qi 05 Área Militar Vi Comar, S/n Parte - Lago Sul, Brasília - DF, Brasil',
    'key' => 'MYKEY'
],
]);
```

a pesquisa direto dessa gera essa url

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?type=gas_station&keyword=posto,combustiveis&query=lago+sul+-+Shi+Sul+Qi+05+%C3%81rea+Militar+Vi+Comar%2C+S%2Fn+Parte+-+Lago+Sul%2C+Bras%C3%ADlia+-+DF%2C+Brasil&key=MYKEY

já pensei que fosse o urlencode mas a busca desse valor no curl é o mesmo que eu jogo no postman ou no chrome mas sempre pelo curl ou guzzle retorna zero results